Maven multimodule project & use of aggregator type of mojos
Not sure if this is a maven bug or failure from our part to use maven as intended so I ask here first instead of going directly to apache jira. Concerns maven v.3.9.0 but seemed to happen also with v.3.9.6 and the latest 4.0.0-alpha-13.
In our project we use a maven multimodule build setup(100+ modules). Full build of all modules takes over an hour so we use gitflow-incremental-builder maven plugin to build a subset suitable for different stages of the development process. For instance, PR build builds only the changed modules + the ones depending on them. In CI we have a pipeline in place that after succesful PR build, using maven-release-plugin, builds a release jar of the changed modules only and deploys them to Azure Artifacts.
One thing to notice here is that we use ranges extensively to depend on jars built by us. There seems to be some longstanding disagreement in the community on how ranges and snapshots should relate. So perhaps this is also part of the problem.
PR build classpath is made of snapshot jars baked during the same multimodule build plus latest release versions from our remote repository in Azure for the modules not in the PR build modules subset. Time ago we started experiencing PR build failures due to dependency ranges not resolving to the snapshot baked earlier during the same build, but instead latest release version from remote repository. That happened even though the snapshot was sitting in the local repository and the snapshot version (e.g. 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT) should be considered more recent than the previous release version (e.g. 1.2.2). After doing some debugging on maven I noticed that executing aggregator type of mojos(in our case serenity-maven-plugins aggregate-goal) result in dependencies being resolved for all the modules/projects which at that point still haven't done that. This happens in halfway of the modules and it won't re-resolve the used ranges later on, missing snapshot jars still to be produced later on during that build.
Maven code seems to take a turn to the wrong path on org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.Mojoexcutor.java:252
public void ensureDependenciesAreResolved(MojoDescriptor mojoDescriptor, MavenSession session, DependencyContext dependencyContext) throws LifecycleExecutionException {
        MavenProject project = dependencyContext.getProject();
        boolean aggregating = mojoDescriptor.isAggregator();
        Collection scopesToCollect;
        Collection scopesToResolve;
        if (dependencyContext.isResolutionRequiredForCurrentProject()) {
            scopesToCollect = dependencyContext.getScopesToCollectForCurrentProject();
            scopesToResolve = dependencyContext.getScopesToResolveForCurrentProject();
            this.lifeCycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(project, scopesToCollect, scopesToResolve, session, aggregating, Collections.emptySet());
            dependencyContext.synchronizeWithProjectState();
        }

        Iterator var8;
        MavenProject aggregatedProject;
        if (aggregating) {
            scopesToCollect = this.toScopes(mojoDescriptor.getDependencyCollectionRequired());
            scopesToResolve = this.toScopes(mojoDescriptor.getDependencyResolutionRequired());
            if (dependencyContext.isResolutionRequiredForAggregatedProjects(scopesToCollect, scopesToResolve)) {
                var8 = session.getProjects().iterator();

                while(var8.hasNext()) {
                    aggregatedProject = (MavenProject)var8.next();
                    if (aggregatedProject != project) {
                    // !!!! Starts resolving all projects in current maven session !!!!
                    this.lifeCycleDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(aggregatedProject, scopesToCollect, scopesToResolve, session, aggregating, Collections.emptySet());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

The Mojo in question is just producing a bunch of report html files under target concerning some Cucumber-tests so we just decided to take it down for now  but I would like to report this behaviour in case it isn't just a user error(which it very well might be). Any insight appreciated.
Expected: Dependency ranges in module poms shouldn't be resolved to an actual version before the module itself is built.

Seems that I was too focused on fixing the problem to actually understand what is the idea of an aggregator goal. The root cause was that the aforementioned serenity:aggregate goal was bound to post-integration-test lifecycle phase in some of the modules. What I came to learn later on is that aggregator goals should never be bound to lifecycle phases but instead directly invoked from command line. The idea is to run them once only for an aggregation of all modules. We went from multirepo setup to maven multimodule build in a monorepo and that lifecycle phase binding that before the migration propably didn't cause problems, now backfired when that maven project became part of a multimodule build.
